# json encoding array of objects within the doctrine object

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, json

I have following doctrine model..

House doctrine entity

```
// Below are not my real object. These are example similar to my originals

// Doctrine entity
class House implements JsonSerializable {
  // Doctrine properties
  protected $id;  // doctrine id field
  protected $rooms; // rooms : one-to-many relation to Room doctrine entity.

  // serializer
  public function jsonSerialize() {
    return [
      'id' => $this->GetId(),
      'rooms' => $this->GetRooms(),
    ];
  }

  // Getters & setters.
  public GetId() { return $this->id; }
  public SetId($id) { $this->id = $id }

  public GetRooms() { return $this->rooms; }
  public SetRooms($rooms) { $this->rooms = $rooms; }
}
```

Following is Room entity

```
// Doctrine entity
class Room implements JsonSerializable {
  protected $id; // doctrine id field

  // serializer
  public function jsonSerialize() {
    return [
      'id' => $this->GetId(),
    ];
  }

  // Getters & setters.
  public GetId() { return $this->id; }
  public SetId($id) { $this->id = $id }
}
```

**Problem ..**

When I fetch one `House` entity using doctrine query, it fetches along with `rooms` objects. But, if I encoded them with `json_encode()` the values for `rooms` seen emtpy.

**Query.. **

```
$qb->select('h', 'r')
  ->from('House', 'h')
  ->where('id = ?1')
  ->leftJoin('h.rooms', 'r')
  ->setParameter('1', $houseId);
```

If I loop through the result set and print the individual item (including `Room` object within `House`) all properties print well. I tried with `Zend\Json\Json::encode()` as well. Still the `rooms` property is empty.

How can I 'json encode' to get the object array within the object to be serialized? Whats the trick?

Comment: Are you also using getters in `jsonSerialize` in your real entity? And what if you add `$query->setFetchMode("House", "rooms", "EAGER");` to your query?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but it is not helpful. The query builder is already doing this eager loading.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code (the part where you're using `json_encode()`)?

Comment: my actual entities have many properties, and entire code to post here is huge. I am using pattern and principle. There are layers of entity -> service -> controllers to go through. The above structure which I have posted is simple view to get the idea.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution:
'rooms' => $this->GetRooms()->toArray()
That will work, because we need an Array, not an Array collection